# Outlines around all of my objects are gone in all projects VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

My initial question was unclear (because to be honest I am not sure what the dotted lines around every control in the form in Design view is called). Reinstated:
All controls I have added to my form have a dotted line around them so you can see their shape and size. Those dotted lines have always been there by default and since have disappeared. I have not changed anything that I know of and now I am unable to view all of my controls because some do not contain text. For example, if you add a label to your form but leave the Text blank, you are unable to see it in design view. There used to be a dotted line around all of my controls so I knew exactly where they were and what size they were. It is now gone.

This is as clear as I can describe it unfortunately.

I have uploaded a pic here [Pic of what it looks like now](http://i48.tinypic.com/aylwfq.png)

These are pictureboxes and there is no easy way to see where their edges are without clicking on them and even then it only shows dots to drag and drop. I used to have dotted lines around all of my controls and now they are "invisible" I need to get them back.

I was able to find a pic of the way it used to be and have uploaded it here:
[Pic of the way it should look like](http://i46.tinypic.com/2d0c4dy.png)

These are Windows forms

I hope this makes sense and I am literally at a stand still until I can get this resolved.

Thanks in advance!

DH

Comment: Take a screenshot of what VS looks like and upload here it so we can see.

Comment: Added pic link to the question :)

Comment: Win forms. And I was able to find a pic of how it looked like before!